# pass one variable from one function to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

After spending days on the web is still haven't found the answer I was looking for...

I need to pass a variable from one function another, `function a` adds 1 when you click it, and `function b` substracts 1 from the number given in `function a`.

so lets say I have this:

```
var x = 0;

function a() {
   x + 1;
}
function b() {
  x - 1;
}
```

Comment: from which function you want to pass?

Comment: `each time you clicked on a` means what ?

Comment: Why do you need to *pass* it? It is in scope for both functions.

Comment: I need to pass x from a to b

Comment: seriously, start here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#Language_basics_crash_course

Comment: Downvoters please explain?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `x` to the result of the addition. The `+` operator returns the result of the addition, it does not change the `x` *in place*.  Something like this will work:

```
var x = 0;

function a() {
   x = x + 1;
}
function b() {
   x = x - 1;
}
```

A shortcut for this is `++` and `--`:

```
var x = 0;

function a() {
   x++;
}
function b() {
   x--;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You write only `x + 1` that dosent increment to `x` value. You have to set `x` value by either `x = x +1` or `x++`.

```
var x = 0;

function a() {
   x++;
   b(x);  //You can pass x value to b function here
}
function b(var x) {
  x--;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xou9tpkv/1/)**

Comment: I really thanks to Downvoter who help me to improve my answer.